# How do I set/read a query string when using the router in aurelia?

Tags: javascript, query-string, aurelia

When using the aurelia.io framework router, what is the preferred method for reading and setting a query string?

For example, in the url: `http://www.myapp.com/#/myroute1/?s=mystate`

How do I read and set the `?s=mystate` part of the url and have the aurelia router navigate correctly and remember that state, such that whenever I arrive in my `route1` viewmodel I can read that state variable and do something with it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On viewmodel you can implement method activate(params, routeConfig) and object params should contain your query variables

```
activate(params, routeConfig){
 console.log(params.s); //should print mystate
}
```

To navigate to some route, you have to specify the name of this route in app.js (name: 'redirect')

```
 config.map([
      { route: ['','welcome'],  moduleId: './welcome',      nav: true, title:'Welcome' },
      { route: 'flickr',        moduleId: './flickr',       nav: true, title:'Flickr' },
      { route: 'redirect', moduleId: './redirect', name: 'redirect'}, 
      { route: 'child-router',  moduleId: './child-router', nav: true, title:'Child Router' }
    ]);
```

and then use method NavigateToRoute with parameters.

```
router.navigateToRoute('redirect', { s:'mystate'}, {replace: true});
```

Comment: Thanks, and how do I set the query string?

Comment: @us3r 1) does router.generate also require {replace: true}? 2) if you are in a different view-model, do import {App} from './app' to access router?

Comment: @ChiRow 1) no, replace is not require, 2) yes, you have to import App (at least i did not found another way to use router).

Comment: @us3r it worked, but only when the route is explicitly named, which isn't very obvious from the api.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change `queryParams` and reload page with it (e.g. change page number on pagination link click) -- you must use `determineActivationStrategy` with `replace`.

Create view model and add `determineActivationStrategy` function:

```
import {activationStrategy} from 'aurelia-router';
export class ModelView{

  determineActivationStrategy() {
    return activationStrategy.replace;
  }

}
```

Add activate event to your model for saving params:

```
activate(params, routeConfig, navigationInstruction){
    this.queryParams = params ? params : {};
}
```

Add code for reload or navigate with same or new parameters:

```
moveToNewPage(newPageNumber){
  this.queryParams.page = newPageNumber; // change page param to new value
  this.router.navigateToRoute(this.router.currentInstruction.config.name, this.queryParams);
}
```

P.S. for `this.router` access use inject and don't forget to set `name` of router in app configuration:

```
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';
export class ModelView{
  static inject() { return [Router] };

  constructor(router){
    this.router = router;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to be nit-picky but shouldn't it be `ViewModel` and not `ModelView`?

Answer (score 1):

As per the latest configuration, the query string will not be retrieved if you didn't set the push state.

Set push state to true. and add base tag in index.html.

`<base href="http://localhost:9000/">` - index.html

`config.options.pushState = true;` - app.js -> configureRouter method.